# Is dotnet-passbook compatible with .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package

I have a task to save a ticket in Apple Wallet. for this I found dotnet-passbook
does this for us. Is it compatible with .net core as well?

Answer (score 2):

No. At the bottom of the [project Github page](https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook#net-core) the developer clearly states:

> **.Net Core**
>
> I've had several people ask whether this library will
>   support .Net Core. If I get the time, I'll try and make this a .Net
>   Standard library, but I'm dependant on Crypto libs etc., so I'll need
>   to evaluate them to ensure they will work .Net Core also.

Comment: Would you please suggest any library for Generating and Saving Apple tickets in Apple wallet?

Comment: I tried 'dotnet-Passbook' and PassSharp packages. both gave Crypto liberary errors. Please suggest what cane be done.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not my area of expertise. I suggest you contact the developer of dotnet-passbook on their github site and direct your questions to them.

Comment: Hello. I'm the developer of dotnet-passbook. I've created a new branch in the repo, which is my first pass at .Net Standard support. Please take a look!